# Cloud Functions for Firebase Could not handle the request after a successful request

Tags: json, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

TLDR: After writing a JSON (successfully) to my Firestore, the next request will give me Internal Server Error (500). I have a suspicion that the problem is that inserting is not yet complete.

So basically, I have this code:

```
const jsonToDb = express();
exports.jsondb = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest(jsonToDb);
jsonToDb.post('', (req, res) => {
    let doc;
    try {
        doc = JSON.parse(req.body);
    } catch(error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.toString()).end();
        return;
    }
    myDbFuncs.saveMyDoc(doc);
    res.status(201).send("OK").end();
}
```

The database functions are in another JS file.

```
module.exports.saveMyDoc = function (myDoc) {
    let newDoc = db.collection('insertedDocs').doc(new Date().toISOString());
    newDoc.set(myDoc).then().catch();
    return;
};
```

So I have several theories, maybe one of them is not wrong, but please help me with this. (Also if I made some mistakes in this little snippet, just tell me.)

Reproduction:

1. I send the first request => everything is OK, Json in the database.
2. I send a second request after the first request give me OK status => it does not do anything for a few secs, then 500: Internal Server Error.

Logs: Function execution took 4345 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'.

I just don't understand. Let's imagine I'm using this as an API, several requests simultaneously. **Can't it handle?** (I suppose it can handle, just I do something stupid.) Deliberately, I'm sending the second request after the first has finished and this occurs.
**Should I make the saveMyDoc async?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

saveMyDoc isn't returning a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.  If you lose track of a promise, Cloud Functions will shut down the work and clean up before the work is complete, making it look like it simply doesn't work.  You should only send a response from an HTTP type function **after** all the work is fully complete.

Minimally, it should look more like this:

```
module.exports.saveMyDoc = function (myDoc) {
    let newDoc = db.collection('insertedDocs').doc(new Date().toISOString());
    return newDoc.set(myDoc);
};
```

Then you would use the promise in your main function:

```
myDbFuncs.saveMyDoc(doc).then(() => {
    res.status(201).send("OK").end();
}
```

See how the response is only sent after the data is saved.

Read more about async programming in Cloud Functions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  Also watch this [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) that talks about working with promises in Cloud Functions.

Comment: I have one more question: I'm using lint, and it gave me an error: 

`Each then() should return a value or throw (promise/always-return)`

Is it good choice to change `res.status(201).send("OK").end();`
 to 
`return res.status(201).send("OK").end();`?

Comment: I would just return null, since the return value of end() doesn't mean anything.